# Multiple formatting of parts of text in a textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

When using chat app like WhatsApp text can be made bold, italics, underline among other text formatting features.

For instance:

> This is a **boy** who can *sing very well* if you only ***allow him*** to do so.

Even stack overflow uses this text formatting feature i.e ** etc instead of the web based one of html tags. I would like to implement it on my app so that i dont use web browser control to do the job because the web browser on windows phone has many set backs compared to the one windows phone.
I have been thinking of making a custom control for this purpose but i have no idea on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in a TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    This is a <Bold>boy</Bold> who can <Italic>sing very well</Italic> if you only <Bold><Italic>allow</Bold></Italic> him to do so.
</TextBlock>
```

For Underline just use `<Underline>Your Underlined Text</Underline>`

You can have a look on [The TextBlock control - Inline formatting](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/) It not only covers Bold Italic Underline but also LineBreak, Hyperlink, Span and formatting from C#/Code-Behind. A lot of samples which inturns make your TextBlock Control to do all set of HTML formatting for the Text

Comment: thanks sir, but can be done in multiple places with a textblock control?

Comment: Yes why not. Have a look at the link I have shared in the answer. All your doubts will be clear

Comment: Hi @JacksonSiro if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Mohit's suggestion require your need and you can follow up the link he provided to achieve your goal, you can also refer to [How to format texts of TextBlock using xaml in Windows Phone](https://raviranjankr.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/how-to-format-texts-of-textblock-using-xaml-in-windows-phone/).

Answer (score 1):

Check [out my implementation](https://github.com/crea7or/DirtyReader/blob/master/DirtyReader/DirtyReader.Shared/Attached%20Properties/RichHtmlText.cs) of `RichTextBlock` that accept Html and builds the text from it. The idea is in supplying attached property, that on change (this property) event will build the internal structure of `RichTextBlock` from supplied in this property html (via parsing html and translating it into `RichTextBlock` blocks).